# Is there a quick method/ heuristic to solve for the length of the optimal route for a simple travelling salesman problem?

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

E.g take this problem:

[image: problem]

You would have about 1 minute and 40 seconds to solve this in an exam. I tried to solve this by listing the permutations of Arford, Yewton and Teechester in between going from and back to Essover.

E.g.

> ATY
>
> AYT
>
> YAT

Is this the fastest method? Also, how can you tell what the number of routes you can take will be?

Comment: I do not see any way to be able to solve a question of this nature within two minutes reliably other than simply solving many of them and coming up with a good method of doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the traveling salesman problem, not the Chinese postman problem.  For $n$ cities, there are $(n-1)!/2$ possible tours, so that is only three tours here.  Just try all three and take the smallest.